# print <break/> tag of xml file using php

Tags: php, html, xml

sorry for my english as it is not good

i have a xml file  which have some   tag

i want to print the element of that xml file with the  tag when ever php find  it 
 plz   if some one know how to print that plz tell the syntsx

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<cars>
   <car id="1">Volvo<break/></car>
   <car id="2">BMW</car>
   <car id="3">Saab</car>
</cars>
```

in string it is possible  to print  using

```
$a= nl2br(str_replace('<br', 'br', $xml));
$a = str_replace("break","&ltBreak",$a);
echo $a;
```

but not in the case of xml file  as during loading it convert the file into  associative array  which not have  tag

so plz tell me how to load xml file such that  their tags are not change or hide

Comment: slash is before break! go with `</break>`

Comment: sir in xml it is after the break